# macOS Swift 3 - Get HFS+ file system partitions list

Tags: swift, macos, filesystems

my first question here, so i am developing a mac tool in swift 3 on macOS to create mac os install drives, i have put together almost all the code i need, but i don't know how to get a list of file system partitions with the 3 following characteristics:

- The partition must be on a drive that uses GUID partition method
- The partition's drive must have an EFI partition
- The partition must use HFS+ as file system

i need that list because that are all the requirements for a partition to being used as mac os installer using the other code i wrote, the third requirement is not the most important since the script that creates the installer formats the partition selected, but at least the first 2 needs to be respected

Comment: Does invoking `diskutil list` command line from your app is possible? (Then parse the output)

Comment: yes, it can be done, but for me is better to find a way to avoid to parse the output, something from the api if possible